# Calculate a field in a GetFeatureInfo request with MapServer 7.0.4

Tags: mapserver, getfeatureinfo

I would like to be able to do some simple calculations on fields returned by a GetFeatureInfo with MapServer 7.0.4.

My case is that I am querying a layer (OGR connection to an ESRI File Geodatabase) and one of the fields returned is the area of a polygon. The area is in square meters but I would like to do an on-the-fly calculation to show the value in acres or hectare.

I didn't find anything in the official documentation indicating that this is possible.

Is it possible, without having to modify the source layer?

Here is the template I use to output the result of the GetFeatureInfo:

```
<!-- MapServer Template -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MapServer Template Sample</title>
  </head>
<table class="bars_n_stripes" border="2">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" width="30%"><center>Attribut</center></th>
                    <th scope="col"><center>Valeur</center></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Numéro de lot</td>    
                    <td>[no_lot_renove]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Prénom</td>
                    <td>[prenom_proprio]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nom</td>
                    <td>[nom_proprio]</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Superficie</td>
                    <td>[shape_area] m<sup>2</sup></td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</html>
```

Comment: It is probably possible with text/html info_format and a template http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html. Are you still interested?

Comment: Yes! Still interested. I still didn't solve my problem. I do use a template to output the result of the GetFeatureInfo

Comment: OK. I must experiment a bit first and it may take a few days before I have time for that.

Comment: I edited my question to include one of the templates I use.

Comment: I had a quick look right away but unfortunately templating http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html does not support any arithmetric operations. I was hoping that they were supported as in expressions http://mapserver.org/mapfile/expressions.html#arithmetic-operations-and-functions-that-return-a-number.

Answer (score 3):

I think in principle it should be possible with JavaScript, for example if you consider the following GetFeatureInfo request:

http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/TFL-PSI/ows?language=eng&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=GBR_Stoke-on-Trent_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=53.0052235378464,-2.28573545848794,53.1251768672774,-2.13175281574312&WIDTH=1086&HEIGHT=846&QUERY_LAYERS=GBR_Stoke-on-Trent_ESA_EN_5k_psi_TS&i=337&j=255&info_format=text/html&

You will see that it includes a Time Series plot that is created on the fly using JavaScript embeded in the template.

[image: Time series plot]

View source to see the JavaScript as created.

The relevant parts of the template here are:

Creating the structure we want to plot:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
var [Id]_tsline=[['1992-05-11',[D19920511]],['1993-01-11',[D19930111]],['1993-02-15',[D19930215]],['1993-03-22',[D19930322]],['1993-05-31',[D19930531]],['1993-08-09',[D19930809]],['1993-10-18',[D19931018]],['1993-11-22',[D19931122]],['1995-04-19',[D19950419]],['1995-05-24',[D19950524]],['1995-05-25',[D19950525]],['1995-06-28',[D19950628]],['1995-06-29',[D19950629]],['1995-08-02',[D19950802]],['1995-08-03',[D19950803]],['1995-10-11',[D19951011]],['1995-10-12',[D19951012]],['1995-12-21',[D19951221]],['1996-02-28',[D19960228]],['1996-02-29',[D19960229]],['1996-04-03',[D19960403]],['1996-04-04',[D19960404]],['1996-05-08',[D19960508]],['1996-05-09',[D19960509]],['1996-06-12',[D19960612]],['1996-07-17',[D19960717]],['1996-08-22',[D19960822]],['1996-10-31',[D19961031]],['1996-12-05',[D19961205]],['1997-01-09',[D19970109]],['1997-02-13',[D19970213]],['1997-03-20',[D19970320]],['1997-04-24',[D19970424]],['1997-05-29',[D19970529]],['1997-08-07',[D19970807]],['1997-09-11',[D19970911]],['1997-10-16',[D19971016]],['1997-11-20',[D19971120]],['1997-12-25',[D19971225]],['1998-01-29',[D19980129]],['1998-03-05',[D19980305]],['1998-04-09',[D19980409]],['1998-05-14',[D19980514]],['1998-06-18',[D19980618]],['1998-07-23',[D19980723]],['1998-08-27',[D19980827]],['1998-10-01',[D19981001]],['1998-11-05',[D19981105]],['1998-12-10',[D19981210]],['1999-02-18',[D19990218]],['1999-03-25',[D19990325]],['1999-08-12',[D19990812]],['1999-09-15',[D19990915]],['1999-09-16',[D19990916]],['1999-10-20',[D19991020]],['1999-10-21',[D19991021]],['1999-11-25',[D19991125]],['1999-12-30',[D19991230]],['2000-02-03',[D20000203]],['2000-03-09',[D20000309]],['2000-04-13',[D20000413]],['2000-05-18',[D20000518]],['2000-06-22',[D20000622]],['2000-07-27',[D20000727]],['2000-08-31',[D20000831]],['2000-11-09',[D20001109]],['2000-12-14',[D20001214]],['2001-10-25',[D20011025]],['2002-10-10',[D20021010]],['2003-02-27',[D20030227]]]; //--> 
</script>
```

Creating a location to put the chart:

```
<tr><td id="[Id]_chart1" class="tschart" title="Time series chart for selected point" style="display:none;"></td></tr>
```

Adding the JavaScript that do the plotting:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
    $("#[Id]_chart1:hidden").show(); 
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('[Id]_chart1', [[Id]_tsline], { 
        title:'Time series plot for selected point', 
        axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}, 
        series:[{lineWidth:3, markerOptions:{style:'circle'}}] 
    }); // --> 
</script>
```

The JavaScript needs to go at the end of the template to allow the page to load before it runs.

Comment: I'll certainly look into it within the next weeks. in the meantime, I used FME to routinely convert my data to PostGIS tables and use PostgreSQL functions to do what I need, server-side.